# What can I use to make a blade-like UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, web-applications, user-interface

I'm building a webapp and since most of the tasks involve the user answering a few questions before posting his content I wanted to create a UI where each question is in one "blade" and when the user clicks OK it moves to the next question on the next "blade"

Like the [blade UI from the old X360 dashboard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4t66-Uq7wQ&t=0m23s), except the user doesn't moves back and forth for different options but to complete the process.

The closest I could find was the [jQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#default), but how do I make it horizontal like in the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a div for each blade, float them all left and give them a width in a containing div, then animate the widths.

Answer (score 0):

The Wijmo accordion will do vertical and horizontal and it's based off of jQuery UI.

http://wijmo.com/